# How can I save data across multiple users on my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I've been working on a simple web page as a demonstration to my boss of how a new feature could turn out.

I'm aware of LocalStorage, and perhaps I misunderstand, but I believe this only stores for one user.

How could I save the data in a manner that could be accessed by anyone opening the page?

I considered using a .txt file but I wasn't sure of the pages ability to access it if it's a web page (path needed, but it's not supposed to be stored on the users computer).

Comment: LocalStorage is stored data into a browser. Not for one user. For example, If the same user does a login from another browser there is no data stored.

Comment: okay that's cool, but how could I do that for anyone across any browser.

Comment: Why don't you try https://firebase.google.com/ firebase?

Comment: check out my answer, that is the only solution that works for every device and browser

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but while your answer may be correct (I can't currently verify) it tells me nothing about how to go about this. It's like if someone asked how they'd go about flying to the moon and someone responded "by building a rocket." Well, yeah, but how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this, I created a JSON file `api.json`. and I created two functions that would either retrieve or set the keys by value.

```
    <?php 
    //Function to get the key!
    function getkey($key) {
      //Decodes the JSON file, then prints the value of the key
      return json_decode(file_get_contents("api.json"))->$key;
    }
    //Function to set the key!
    function setkey($key, $value){
      //Fetches the json file
      $theapi = json_decode(file_get_contents("api.json"));
      //Sets the key to the value
      $theapi->$key = $value;
      //Puts the returned file in api.json
      file_put_contents("api.json", json_encode($theapi));
    }

    echo getkey("somekey") . "<br>";
    //Go to https://php-db.ch1ck3n.repl.co/?towhat=somevalue to set it to somevalue!
    setkey("somekey", $_GET["towhat"]);
    echo getkey("somekey");
    ?>
```

And `api.json` would probably look something like this: `{"somekey":"somevalue"}`

working demo:

https://repl.it/@ch1ck3n/PHP-DB#index.php

(note that since it is a global variable, it updates every time someone loads!)

you can also go to https://php-db.ch1ck3n.repl.co/?towhat=somevalue to change `somekey` to `somevalue`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a DB (database) to store your data and an API to do requests such:

- POST requests you save the data from the users
- GET requests every time the page is rendered, so the users are
  up-to-date with "real-time" data.